# 'let' property may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead

Tags: swift, generics, initialization, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I want to try to write a default `init` in a `protocol` extension, so I did this:

```
protocol P {
    var data: [AnyHashable: Any] { get }
    init(_ s: String)
}

extension P {
    init(_ s: String) {
        self.data = ["s": s]
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> 'let' property 'data' may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead

I have no idea what it means. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error says that the variable cannot be initialized in the protocol extension because it's declared as constant `{ get }`

But even if you declare the variable `{ get set }` you can't use the `init` method anyway without a constraint to a concrete type or an associated type.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. The first part makes complete sense, however I'm not sure to understand "you can't use the `init` method anyway without a constraint to a concrete type or an associated type". Sorry if this is basic but I'm a little new to Swift so this is still a bit complicated for me.

Comment: A protocol is not a concrete type. You cannot initialize an instance of `P`. You can only initialize a concrete type, an associated type or a generic type.

Comment: 1. Would you mind integrating your comment into the answer. It's really helpful for understanding the answer. I tried incorporating your comment into your answer, but I hesitated because as I had some questions: 2. You said: _You can only initialize a concrete type, an associated type or a generic type._ . I get that you can't initialize a protocol type. I understand that you can initialize concrete and generic types. But how can you initialize with a constraint to a vanilla associated type like `Element`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import PlaygroundSupport

protocol P {
    var data: [AnyHashable: Any] { get }
    var _data: [AnyHashable: Any] { get set }
    static func generator(_ s: String) -> P
    init()
}

extension P {
    static func generator(_ s: String) -> P {
        var p = self.init()
        p._data = ["s": s]
        return p
    }
}

class A: P {
    required init() { }
    var data: [AnyHashable : Any] {
        return _data
    }
    var _data: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]
}

let a = A.generator("some")
print(a.data)

PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
```

I think this is the closest code you want. The problem is that `_data` is shared by other classes.

Comment: Thank you for that. Using a static func instead of an init seems an interesting workaround.